# Analizador Lexico en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de escáner léxico en JavaScript para analizar el lenguaje ficticio C--.

He creado una interfaz de usuario utilizando un documento HTML básico. En el cuerpo del documento, he agregado un formulario (`<form>`) que contiene un área de texto (`<textarea>`) donde el usuario puede ingresar el código que desea analizar. También he incluido un botón (`<button>`) para iniciar el proceso de análisis.

Sin embargo, estoy experimentando problemas al ejecutar el código JavaScript. No puedo identificar la razón por la cual el código no se está ejecutando correctamente. Apreciaría mucho su ayuda para resolver este problema.

Además, adjunto la tabla de transiciones, DFA y la tabla de tokens que he utilizado para este proyecto. Esto puede ser útil para comprender mejor mi implementación y brindar una solución más precisa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
// Definir las constantes de los tokens conforme a la tabla de transiciones y el DFA
const TOKEN_INT = 1;
const TOKEN_IF = 2;
const TOKEN_READ = 3;
const TOKEN_FLOAT = 4;
const TOKEN_ELSE = 5;
const TOKEN_WRITE = 6;
const TOKEN_STRING = 7;
const TOKEN_WHILE = 8;
const TOKEN_VOID = 9;
const TOKEN_FOR = 10;
const TOKEN_RETURN = 11;
const TOKEN_ADD = 12;
const TOKEN_SUBTRACT = 13;
const TOKEN_MULTIPLY = 14;
const TOKEN_DIVIDE = 15;
const TOKEN_LESS_THAN = 16;
const TOKEN_LESS_THAN_EQUAL = 17;
const TOKEN_GREATER_THAN = 18;
const TOKEN_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL = 19;
const TOKEN_ASSIGN = 20;
const TOKEN_EQUAL = 21;
const TOKEN_NOT_EQUAL = 22;
const TOKEN_SEMICOLON = 23;
const TOKEN_COMMA = 24;
const TOKEN_OPEN_PAREN = 25;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_PAREN = 26;
const TOKEN_OPEN_BRACKET = 27;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACKET = 28;
const TOKEN_OPEN_BRACE = 29;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACE = 30;
const TOKEN_IDENTIFIER = 31;
const TOKEN_STRING_CONSTANT = 32;
const TOKEN_INTEGER_CONSTANT = 33;
const TOKEN_FLOAT_CONSTANT = 34;

// Definir los estados
const STATE_START = 0;
const STATE_IDENTIFIER = 1;
const STATE_NUMBER = 2;
const STATE_FLOAT = 3;
const STATE_COMMENT = 4;
const STATE_STRING_CONSTANT = 5;
const STATE_ERROR = 6;
const STATE_DONE = 7;

const TRANSITION_TABLE = [
    [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 28, 12, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 0],
    [1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13],
    [40, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 3, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
    [40, 4, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
    [15, 4, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
    [16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
    [18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18],
    [20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
    [40, 40, 40, 40, 22, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
    [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 10, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
    [ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ],
    [ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 24, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ],
    [ 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 25, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 ]
];

const advance = [
{ other: true },
{ other: true },
{ other: true },
{ other: true },
{ other: true },
{ other: true },
{ other: true },
{ other: true },
];

// Definir los caracteres de entrada correspondientes a cada columna en la matriz de transición
const DIGITS = '0123456789';
const LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const WHITESPACE = ' \n\t';
const DELIMITERS = WHITESPACE + '+-*/<>=!;,.()[]{}';
const COMMENT_START = '/*';
const COMMENT_END = '*/';

let currentInputPos = 0;
function nextInputChar() {
// Leer un caracter del archivo de entrada o de un input de usuario en el navegador
const input = document.getElementById('inputTextArea').value;
if (currentInputPos >= input.length) {
  return '';
}
const inputChar = input[currentInputPos];
// Actualizar el puntero de lectura del archivo de entrada o del input de usuario
currentInputPos++;
return inputChar;
}

let tokens = [];

function recordToken(tokenType, lexeme, line) {
// Agregar el token encontrado al arreglo de tokens
tokens.push({ type: tokenType, lexeme: lexeme, line: line });
// Imprimir el token encontrado en consola o mostrarlo en el navegador
console.log(`Token encontrado: ${tokenType} - ${lexeme} (linea ${line})`);
}

function lex() {
let state = STATE_START;
let lexeme = '';
let line = 1;

while (state !== STATE_DONE) {
  const inputChar = nextInputChar();

  switch (state) {
    case STATE_START:
      if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_NUMBER;
        lexeme += inputChar;
      } else if (LETTERS.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_IDENTIFIER;
        lexeme += inputChar;
      } else if (inputChar === '/') {
        state = STATE_COMMENT;
      } else if (inputChar === '"') {
        state = STATE_STRING_CONSTANT;
      } else if (DELIMITERS.includes(inputChar)) {
        recordToken(getDelimiterType(inputChar), inputChar, line);
      } else if (inputChar === '') {
        state = STATE_DONE;
      } else if (!WHITESPACE.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_ERROR;
      }
      break;

        case STATE_NUMBER:
          if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else if (inputChar === '.') {
            state = STATE_FLOAT;
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            recordToken(TOKEN_INTEGER_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_FLOAT:
          if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            recordToken(TOKEN_FLOAT_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_IDENTIFIER:
          if (LETTERS.includes(inputChar) || DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            const tokenType = getKeywordType(lexeme);
            recordToken(tokenType, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_COMMENT:
          if (inputChar === '\n' || inputChar === '') {
            state = STATE_START;
            line++;
          } else if (inputChar === '*' && nextInputChar() === '/') {
            state = STATE_START;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_STRING_CONSTANT:
          if (inputChar === '"') {
            recordToken(TOKEN_STRING_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          } else if (inputChar === '') {
            state = STATE_ERROR;
          } else {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          }
          break;

      case STATE_ERROR:
        console.log(`Error: Caracter inesperado '${inputChar}' en la línea ${line}`);
        state = STATE_DONE;
        break;
    }
  }
}

// Función para obtener el tipo de delimitador
function getDelimiterType(char) {
  switch (char) {
    case '+':
      return TOKEN_ADD;
    case '-':
      return TOKEN_SUBTRACT;
    case '*':
      return TOKEN_MULTIPLY;
    case '/':
      return TOKEN_DIVIDE;
    case '<':
      return TOKEN_LESS_THAN;
    case '<=':
      return TOKEN_LESS_THAN_EQUAL;
    case '>':
      return TOKEN_GREATER_THAN;
    case '>=':
      return TOKEN_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL;
    case '=':
      return TOKEN_ASSIGN;
    case '==':
      return TOKEN_EQUAL;
    case '!=':
      return TOKEN_NOT_EQUAL;
    case ';':
      return TOKEN_SEMICOLON;
    case ',':
      return TOKEN_COMMA;
    case '(':
      return TOKEN_OPEN_PAREN;
    case ')':
      return TOKEN_CLOSE_PAREN;
    case '[':
      return TOKEN_OPEN_BRACKET;
    case ']':
      return TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACKET;
    case '{':
      return TOKEN_OPEN_BRACE;
    case '}':
      return TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACE;
    default:
      return -1; // Delimitador desconocido
  }
}

// Función para obtener el tipo de palabra clave
function getKeywordType(lexeme) {
  switch (lexeme) {
    case 'int':
      return TOKEN_INT;
    case 'if':
      return TOKEN_IF;
    case 'read':
      return TOKEN_READ;
    case 'float':
      return TOKEN_FLOAT;
    case 'else':
      return TOKEN_ELSE;
    case 'write':
      return TOKEN_WRITE;
    case 'string':
      return TOKEN_STRING;
    case 'while':
      return TOKEN_WHILE;
    case 'void':
      return TOKEN_VOID;
    case 'for':
      return TOKEN_FOR;
    case 'return':
      return TOKEN_RETURN;
    default:
      return TOKEN_IDENTIFIER;
  }
}

// Ejemplo de uso
lex();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Analizador Léxico</title>
  <script src="scanner.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="codeForm">
    <textarea id="inputTextArea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="lex()">Analizar</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    function lex() {
      tokens = []; // Reiniciar el arreglo de tokens antes de cada análisis
      currentInputPos = 0; // Reiniciar la posición de lectura del input
      
      const input = document.getElementById('inputTextArea').value;
      
      // Llamar a la función lex() para realizar el análisis léxico
      lex();

      // Hacer algo con los tokens obtenidos, como mostrarlos en el navegador o procesarlos más
      console.log(tokens);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

#### Edición

Hice el siguiente cambio, pero aún no corre.

```
function lexAn() {
    let state = STATE_START;
    let lexeme = '';
    let line = 1;
    while (state !== STATE_DONE) {
       const inputChar = nextInputChar();
       switch (state) {
```

El HTML ahora se ve así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Analizador Léxico</title>
  <script src="scanner.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="codeForm">
    <textarea id="inputTextArea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="analizar()">Analizar</button> <!-- Se cambió el nombre de la función a "analizar" -->
  </form>

  <script>
    function analizar() { // Se cambió el nombre de la función a "analizar"
      tokens = []; // Reiniciar el arreglo de tokens antes de cada análisis
      currentInputPos = 0; // Reiniciar la posición de lectura del input
      
      const input = document.getElementById('inputTextArea').value;
      
      // Llamar a la función lexAn() para realizar el análisis léxico
      lexAn();

      // Hacer algo con los tokens obtenidos, como mostrarlos en el navegador o procesarlos más
      console.log(tokens);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero aún me da error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: lexAn is not defined
>
> at analizar (index.htl :22:7)
>
> at HTMLButtonE1ernent.onc1ick (index. HTML:11:48)

Comment: Hola ZGB, bienvenido, para empezar, en tu **`js`**, la ultima linea es **lex();**, con lo que llamas a dicha función antes de escribir nada en el `inputTextArea`, lo que hace que tu programa entre en un bucle infinito, después, en el `html`, tienes un `script` con la función **lex()**, lo que me hace bastante ruido, ya que hay dos funciones con el mismo nombre, quité el `script` y funciona igual... pero yo lo quitaría, por lo demás parece funcionar bien (no lo he probado a fondo).

Comment: [C--](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--) no es un lenguaje ficticio. Si creaste tu propio lenguaje y le pusiste así es otra cosa.

Comment: @marce-puente gracias, hice unos cambios, que ya actualice en la consulta, entre ellos eliminar el lex del final, y le cambie el nombre a lexAn, pero aun me da error

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiada extensa, considera adjuntar un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hola de nuevo, para que algunos de nuestros colegas.... en fin, en tu `js` renombra la función **`lex`** y llamala **`lexAn`**, con eso debería funcionar (a mi me funciona), más allá de eso, tu código tiene algún problemin, ya que por ejemplo, no me detecta un `int`, mi sugerencia, es que revises bien cual es el error, y crees una nueva pregunta al respecto.

Comment: ya cambie los nombres pero me da este error y no funciona:

Uncaught ReferenceError: lexAn is not defined

at analizar (index.htl :22:7)

at HTMLButtonE1ernent.onc1ick (index. HTML:11:48)

Answer (score 0):

- El primer problema con tu código es que has declarado dos funciones llamadas `lex()`. Una dentro del script referenciado y otra dentro de la etiqueta `<script>` del HTML.

  Cuando esto ocurre, javascript utiliza solamente la función que aparece más adelante en el código, prueba esto:

  ```js
  function funcion() {
    console.log("primera funcion")
  }

  function funcion() {
    console.log("segunda funcion")
  }

  funcion();
  ```
- El segundo problema es que, dentro de la función `lex()` declarada en el HTML, haces una llamada a `lex();`, seguramente pensando que estás invocando a la función que está dentro del archivo js referenciado.

  Pero no, lo que estás haciendo es una llamada recursiva a la misma `lex()` que está dentro del HTML. Dado que esta llamada se realiza de manera incondicional, esto crea un ciclo infinito que se va a romper solamente cuándo se llene la pila de llamadas y ocurra un StackOverflow.

  Para ejemplificar esto, prueba el siguiente código, que tiene una variable de control para que la llamada recursiva ocurra solo unas cuantas veces y puedas ver el resultado.

  ```js
  let x = 0;
  function funcion() {
    console.log("primera funcion")
  }

  function funcion() {
    console.log("segunda funcion");
    x = x + 1;
    if (x < 10) {
      funcion();
    }
  }

  funcion();
  ```
- Finalmente, dentro del archivo tenes una llamada directa a `lex()`, que en realidad no debiera estar allí.

La solución al estos problemas es tan fácil como renombrar la función que está dentro de tu HTML, por ejemplo ponerle `analizar()`, y actualizar el `onclick` del botón para que llame a `analizar()` y no a `lex()`.

Luego, quitar la llamada a `lex()` que está en la última línea de archivo `scanner.js`.

Ya hacer que la función `lex()` funcione correctamente, queda fuera del alcance de esta respuesta.

Comment: ya lo corregí pero da error

Comment: "da error" no es la mejor descripción si buscas ayuda. Qué error? en qué momento exacto?. Comento que yo hice ese cambio y probé, antes de responder, y obtenía en la consola el primer _token_ del código que estuviera en el textarea, sin errores.

Comment: lo puse abajo como una respuesta, y una disculpa si no es la mejor manera pero soy nuevo en la plataforma, pero resumido el error es este:

Uncaught ReferenceError: lexAn is not defined
at analizar (index.htl :22:7)
at HTMLButtonE1ernent.onc1ick (index. HTML:11:48)

Comment: Aquí no existe arriba o abajo, pues siempre puedes ordenar las respuestas de diferentes maneras. StackOverflow no es un viejo sistema de foros, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio. Por otro lado, no sé de dónde ha salido ese `lexAn` que mencionas. ¿Seguiste mis recomendaciones al pie de la letra? Un saludo.

Comment: ya añadi la actualización a la consulta, y si segui tu recomendacion, el lexAn sigue siendo el lex original solo lo cambie para denotar el cambio pero sigue siendo la misma función

Answer (score 0):

No tengo muy fresco Javascript ahora, pero me ha surgido una duda viendo tu código, y es que no le veo el sentido a declarar una variable destinada al almacenamiento de cada palabra o carácter de un texto de forma recursiva o reiterativa con el tipo de una constante. Por darte mi opinión a esto, me parece que abusas de requisitos de memoria. Mucha variable y mucha constante, te has planteado analizar caracteres mediante su valores ASCII por rangos numéricos devueltos y tablas?
Crearía primero una función que acepte cualquier argumento de tipo text en su invocación, con nombre de identificador "Analizador", dentro del cuerpo de instrucciones definiría la forma de analizar y clasificar el valor pasado por parámetro según si su valor ASCII corresponde dentro de un rango numérico u otro, según si son letras minúsculas o mayúsculas, si son números o si son símbolos. Esto siempre pensando en el caso de chars sueltos, en el caso de ser mayor de un char, comprobar si el resultado de concatenar los valores ASCII concuerdan con las palabras reservadas del lenguaje específico que esté analizando.
Todo este peñazo para que... para poder retornar dentro otra función recursiva el resultado según lo deseado, pudiendo registrarlo mediante el almacenamiento que prefieras, BBSS, caché, sistema de ficheros, etc.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bienvenido. Esto parece más un comentario. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar en todos lados. Cualquier posible solución a la pregunta es bienvenida.